# Syntax to add attributes in a line in the Expression String Builder

Tags: qgis, style, fields-attributes, field-calculator

I have several columns with certain values, here's an example:

```
  | Apple | Banana| Orange | Pear       | Expected result
  | 1     | 1     | 1      | 1          | red
  | 1     | 2     | 2      | 1          | green
  | 2     | 1     | 1      | 1          | red
  | 2     | 2     | 2      | 1          | green
```

I would like to add **ALL** columns **ONLY** when the values are 2. I'm using this as a style filter so there will be colour ranges (i.e. `Apple` + `Banana` + `Orange` + `Pear`is less than 4 then red; equal or greater than 4 then green).

Can this be done?

The following is, I think, close to what I want but it gives `red` for all results instead of the expected results as shown above:

```
case when "Apple" IN ('2') + "Banana" IN ('2') + "Orange" IN ('2') + "Pear" IN ('2')
>=4 then 'green'
else 'red'
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the rule description is not yet completely clear for me. Please clarify: Would it be correct to say that you want to count how often the value 2 appears in a line? And if it appears at least twice, the color should be green?

Comment: @underdark, yes that is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
CASE
WHEN ("Apple" = 2) + ("Banana" = 2) + ("Orange" = 2) + ("Pear" = 2) >= 2
THEN 'green'
ELSE 'red'    
END
```